# Google Plus Can't create the post. Try again later

Tags: ios, google-plus

When i try to open the native GPP share dialog on my IOS application I got the following error:

[image]

Using web based share does work as expected. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)shareGooglePlus:(id)sender {

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.clientID = kClientID;
    signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, 
                     nil];

    signIn.delegate = self;
    if (![signIn trySilentAuthentication]){
        [signIn authenticate];
    }
}

- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error
{
    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] 
                                                  nativeShareDialog];
}
```

Thank's in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got the Google+ API enabled in the API console project for that client ID?